# best way to update array child values in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout observableArray that has an IsRecent (bool) item.  The IsRecent denotes whether the record updated was done over/under a minute ago.  When IsRecent is true, I highlight the row using knockout's attr with css.  When I load the knockout observableArray from the database, I calculate that via the MVC ViewModel.  Works like a charm.

Now, instead of loading the entire table all the time, I only update records/entire rows that changes by using ko.util.push/ko.util.replace.  That works great...

When I push/replace one record, I would like to go through the entire table and update one measly field -- IsRecent.  Question is... how?

What I'm doing below doesn't seem to work:

```
    function setIsRecentHighlight() {
       var now = new Date();
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(taskViewModel.tasks(), function(task) {
           var stamp = new Date(task.LastActivityStampUtc);
           var ms = Math.abs(stamp - now);
           if (ms > 60000 && task.IsRecent) {
              var index = taskViewModel.tasks.indexOf(task);
              task.IsRecent = false;
              taskViewModel.tasks.replace(taskViewModel.tasks()[index], task);
          }
       });
    }
```

the viewModel:

```
var taskViewModel = {
    tasks: ko.observableArray()
}
```

tasks has:

```
{"tasks":[
{"$id":"1","Name":"Report1","LastActivityStampUtc":"2013-01-14T12:52:14.420Z","IsRecent":true",
{"$id":"2","Name":"Report2","LastActivityStampUtc":"2013-01-14T12:47:32.700Z","IsRecent":false"}]
}
```

Comment: It be should `task.IsRecent(false);` if `IsRecent` an observable property. If not observable make it observable and it should work.

Comment: How shall I make it observable? Map it somehow? Otherwise, I'd have to make this viewModel into a function?